Load Nuxt version >=3.9.0 with expressjs (Custom Server)
i want to load nuxt framework with version 3.11.2. I load in file index.js like code below
const express = require("express");
const { build, loadNuxt } = require("nuxt");
const { default: main, createHttpService } = require("@tinqjs/tinjs-boot");

const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const app = express();

// console.log(nuxt);

main(async () => {
  const nuxt = await loadNuxt(isDev ? "dev" : "start");

  // Use Nuxt's renderer
  app.use(nuxt.render);

  if (isDev) {
    await build(nuxt);
  }

  const listen = createHttpService(app);

  listen(3001, () => {
    console.log(`Service frontend nuxtjs ready`);
  });
});

and i run with node index.js but i have got an error
Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: No "exports" main defined in /node_modules/nuxt/package.json

How to resolve this error? Please, help me...

Why do you use CJS here (require), please use ESM (import).

my bad, sometimes i confused with CJS and ESM. thankyou for your help. the code working

OP used ESM import rather than the CJS one (require) and this fixed the issue!

Next with this case, i want to load Nuxt framework with version 3.11.2 but the nuxt.render is undefined makes the app.use(nuxt.render); need middleware. how to resolve this case??

@armandowni please open a new question.
